# mongodb native driver get collection names without database name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

How can I get collection names without database name from mongodb native driver for nodeJS?

```
db.collectionNames(function(err, collections) {
      if (err) {
        log.error(err);
      } else {
        log.info(collections);
      }
    });
```

This code returns something like this:

> databaseName.collection1, databaseName.collection2, databaseName.collection3

But i want to get names: `collection1, collection2, collection3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact structure of the response is a sub-document with the "name" key in an array:

```js
[
  { name: 'test.cursors' },
  { name: 'test.episodes' },
  { name: 'test.zips' },
  { name: 'test.scripts' }
]
```

So just use `map` with a regex `replace`:

```js
db.collectionNames(function(err, collections) {

  console.log(
    collections.map(function(x) {
      return x.name.replace(/^([^.]*)./,"");
    })
  );

});
```

And that will strip out everything up to the first `.` which is the database prefix. Just in case you actually have collection names with a `.` in them.

Answer (score 14):

With the MongoDB 2.0.0 driver and higher, you'll [need to use `listCollections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/changes-from-1.0/), as in

```
db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections){
    //collections = [{"name": "coll1"}, {"name": "coll2"}]
});
```